# Как оптимизировать Dockerfile для сборки aab?

Tags: docker

У меня есть пет проект который я выгружаю в google play, написал такой dockerfile для сборки данного проекта, проект на apache cordova, как будет лучше оптимизировать это или сделать более правильнее?

```
FROM node:14.21.3 as build-stage

# Устанавливаем необходимые зависимости и Android SDK
ENV ANDROID_HOME /opt/android-sdk-linux
ENV PATH ${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/tools/bin

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk gradle wget unzip && \
    wget -q "https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6609375_latest.zip" -O /tmp/tools.zip && \
    mkdir -p ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools && \
    unzip /tmp/tools.zip -d ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools && \
    rm -rf /tmp/tools.zip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    npm install -g cordova && \
    yes | sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-30" "build-tools;33.0.2"

# Устанавливаем зависимости проекта и собираем проект
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build 

# Подготовка Cordova
RUN rm -rf mobileapp/www && cp -r dist mobileapp/www
WORKDIR mobileapp/www
RUN cordova platform add android && \
    cordova build android --release

# Этот Dockerfile будет создавать APK в /app/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/
```